# Converting an input field into a Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, html, redux-form

I have a pretty basic question to ask but can anybody please tell me if there is any way to convert an input into a Rich Text Editor?? I did some googling but I cannot find a clear explanation regarding this topic.
I can't and don't want to use a div with contentEditable as true nor do I want to manipulate the input of the div and send it to some hidden input tag using JS and then use it to send the form due to project limitations.
I'm using Redux Form in a MERN Stack-based app and the redux form value doesn't seem to catch the value when I send the HTML of the div of Rich Text Editor to a hidden input using JQuery.
Please, somebody, tell me a possible solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try Jodit editor. Its open source and can be used on textarea.

This is the examples link:- https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/textarea/

This is the documentation link :- https://xdsoft.net/jodit/doc/

Comment: Can I use this commercially for free? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes you can as it is open source.

Comment: Another issue, I'm trying to send the value of the Rich Text Editor entered by the user to a text area by using the ``value`` so that I can send the values to the backend but Redux Form is not capturing the value passed into it when I console log out the current state. Please tell a solution.

Comment: I can't upvote I need atleast 15 reputation to do so (yes, I don't even have 15 rep)